# joblib.Parallel for nested list comprehension

Tags: python, syntax, parallel-processing, list-comprehension, joblib

I have a nested list comprehension that looks something like this:

```
>>> nested = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> [[sqrt(i) for i in j] for j in nested]
[[1.0, 1.4142135623730951], [1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979]]
```

Is it possible to parellelize this using the [standard joblib approach for embarrassingly parallel for loops](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)? If so, what is the proper syntax for `delayed`?

As far as I can tell, the docs don't mention or give any example of nested inputs. I've tried a few naive implementations, to no avail:

```
>>> #this syntax fails:
>>> Parallel(n_jobs = 2) (delayed(sqrt)(i for i in j) for j in nested)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 660, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 512, in retrieve
    self._output.append(job.get())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'generator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.generator
>>> #this syntax doesn't fail, but gives the wrong output:
>>> Parallel(n_jobs = 2) (delayed(sqrt)(i) for i in j for j in nested)
[1.7320508075688772, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979]
```

If this is impossible, I can obviously restructure the list before and after passing it to `Parallel`. However, my actual list is long and each item is enormous, so doing so isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what's happening in your second attempt, but the first one is clear to me:
The expression in brackets behind the `sqrt`, `(i for i in j)` results in a ["generator"](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) object, which is passed to the parallel processing pipeline. Unfortunately, the output of a generator may be dependent on previous calls. In your case, it will provide the next element of j every time it's being called, but it might as well do some internal calculations which would mean that the different processes are dependent on each other, and that your results might become dependent on the order in which the parallel processes are executed. For that reason, the `multiprocessing` library refuses to continue.

As I said, I'm not quite sure what's happening in the second example but it might just be that you managed to accidentally trick `multiprocessing` into doing exactly what it tried to avoid in the first case.

**Potential solutions:**

*1: Separate the levels of iteration*

...for example, as j_n suggests, by defining a function which will iterate on the low-level lists. This is easy to implement but may not give you as much benefit from parallelization, depending on how long the individual lists turn out to be.
It might also be an option to use non-parallel list comprehension for the outer loop but parallelize the inner one, or even both -- whether this is useful pretty much depends on the structure of your data.

*2: Iterate on a linearised version of your nested list*

That way, every single execution is done in parallel, but it means you need to "flatten" the list first and restructure it later.

This is easy if your nested list is regularly structured (i.e. if it contains n lists with m elements each:

making a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.htmlhttp://) from the nested list, like so:

```
import numpy as np
# convert to array -- only works well if you have a regular structure!
nested_arr = np.array(nested)
# the shape of the array, for later
shape = nested_arr.shape

# generate an (n*m) linear array from an (n, m) 2D one
linear = nested_arr.ravel()

# run the parallel calculation
results_lin = Parallel(n_jobs = 2) (delayed(sqrt)(e) for e in linear)

# get everything back into shape:
results = results_lin.reshape(shape)
```

Actually, this might be even simpler because `np.nditer()` iterate element-wise over a multidimensional array. I'm not sure whether it will cooperate with `joblib` and `multiprocessing`, though.
If you have regular data (and you really just want to do nothing much more complicated than get a square root) , you should also consider simply using `np.sqrt(nested_arr)` -- this executes much quicker than iterating over a list of numbers and squaring them separately, by orders of magnitude!

If your nested list is irregular, linearising becomes a bit more involved:

```
# store lengths of the sub-lists
structure = [len(e) for e in nested]

# make one linear list
linlist = []
for l in nested:
    linlist.extend(l)

# finally run the parallel computation:
results_lin = Parallel(n_jobs = 2) (delayed(sqrt)(e) for e in linlist)

# ...and bring it all back into shape:
results = []
i = 0

for n in structure:
    results.append(results_lin[i:i+n])
```

Whether all this makes sense again depends on the amount of data you're treating, and the complexity of your list. With your simple example, obviously the sorting will take longer than computing square roots.

**Do you really need parallelisation, though?**

If all you're doing is simple maths on a large amount of numbers, consider using `np.array`. You can put arrays into most equations as if they were numbers, and calculations run much faster:

```
In [14]: time resl = [sqrt(e) for e in range(1000000)]
CPU times: user 2.1 s, sys: 194 ms, total: 2.29 s
Wall time: 2.19 s

In [15]: time res = np.sqrt(np.arange(1000000))
CPU times: user 10.4 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 10.4 ms
Wall time: 10.1 ms
```

This is **way faster** than what the operation on the list could be accelerated to, even running parallel on 24 cores. (in fact, you'd need about 216  parallel processes to keep up with `numpy`, and I'm sure the computational effort of `mutliprocessing` distributing load to that many processes would doom the attempt anyway.

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project, and wound up implementing this in a different language, so I can't test any of the solutions here. However, the information matches my best understanding from further research, and I appreciate you coming back and providing such a thorough answer to a long abandoned question!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, you cannot enter an expression (like `(i for i in j)`) at that position - you put the argument to the function there. You can achieve what you want by writing a function that does the unpacking of the list, such as here:

```
def sqrt_n(j):
   return [i**i for i in j]

Parallel(n_jobs = 2) (delayed(sqrt_n)(j) for j in nested)
```

Comment: `As far as I understand it...` can you elaborate? Are you confident this can't be done, or just don't know how to do it? Your workaround is reasonable, but potentially inefficient, because it would pass each inner list in its entirety to a single core, rather than passing each element.

Comment: (I didn't downvote, by the way- but if the downvoter believes this answer is incorrect, I would love to hear why...)